# Differentiating Lead Source by Referral Source

Tags: leads

I'd like to know if I can show if website leads submitted came from organic search vs. seeing an ad then submitting a lead form.

Is it possible to have Salesforce track behavior back to see where the lead came from?

Comment: If you can capture how user is reaching the lead form then use that indicator or value and save it as Lead Source

Comment: most marketing automation systems like hubspot (and their integration to sfdc) handle this natively

Answer (score 0):

Google has a feature that lets you send AdWords data in your web-to-lead form, outlined in [About AdWords Conversion](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6179720?hl=en). Other systems like Yahoo and Bing also provide relevant tools so you can track organic vs ad-targeting searches if you use those systems instead.